# How to only get the Ids from a FluentNhibernate HasManyToMany mapping

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, many-to-many

Say I have two Entities.

```
public class Category{
    public virtual int Id{get;set;}
    public virtual IList<Post> Posts{get;set;}
}

public class Post{
    public virtual int Id{get;set;}
    public virtual string Title{get;set;}
}
```

In the Db there's a many-to-many table

> CategoryPostRel
>
> - CategoryId
> - PostId

The category Map then looks like this:

```
public CategoryMap()
    {   
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Posts)
            .Table("CategoryPostRel")
            .ParentKeyColumn("CategoryId")
            .ChildKeyColumn("PostId");
    }
```

Ok, but say I only want the Ids from the Posts. So I change my Category entity to look like this.

```
    public class Category{
    public virtual int Id{get;set;}
    public virtual IList<int> PostIds{get;set;}
}
```

### So now, how do I get the ids with my mapping as the HasManyToMany maps Entities, not columns right?

**Note that I can't change the db at all and the many-to-many table has no unique identifier.**

```
    public CategoryMap()
    {   
        HasManyToMany(x => x.PostIds)
            .Table("CategoryPostRel")
            .ParentKeyColumn("CategoryId")
            .ChildKeyColumn("PostId").HowDoIgetTheIds...?
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an entity that models this relationship `CategoryPost` and do something like this:

```
public CategoryMap()
{   
    HasMany(x => x.CategoryPostIds)
        .KeyColumn("CategoryId")

}

public CategoryPostMap
{
    CompositeId()
        .KeyProperty(x => x.PostId)
        .KeyProperty(x => x.CategoryId)
}
```

This is obviously not an ideal solution but it may work.

Comment: +1 ahh... ok. This sounds good. So, I tried this extra entity approach but because the many-to-many doest have a primary key I couldn't map it. The CompositeId method solves this issue? is that right?